# Why does jQuery's ajax automatically run scripts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iframe, jquery-plugins

I noticed recently that if jQuery ajax is called right after injecting jQuery into an inner iframe, jQuery loses its functions - like jQuery(..).dialog(), .draggable, and any other plugins. If the ajax call is commented out, the jQuery works fine. Is this a known bug, or something I'm doing wrong? This problem can be seen in this file, with jQuery in the same directory:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

Try and <button id="btn">load</button>
<iframe width=300 height=300></iframe>

<script>
"use strict";
jQuery('#btn').click(function(){
    var $ = jQuery;
    console.log(typeof jQuery('iframe').dialog);
    var doc = jQuery('iframe')[0].contentDocument;
    function insertscript(src) {
        var newscript = doc.createElement('script');
        newscript.setAttribute('src',src);
        doc.documentElement.appendChild(newscript);
    }
    insertscript('jquery.js');

    //This breaks the jQuery plugins:
    var test = $.get('jquery.js',function(){
        //Now we know jQuery should be in the frame.
    });

    //So does this:
    //jQuery.ajax({url:'http://192.168.1.17/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js',cache:true,processData:false});

    console.log(typeof jQuery('iframe').dialog);
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        //jQuery is no longer the original jQuery object. Note the cached reference $().dialog does exist though.
        console.log('after awhile... dialog is ' + typeof jQuery('iframe').dialog);
    },3000)
    //jQuery.ajax({url:jqurl,cache:true,processData:false});
});
</script>
</body></html>
```

This is a minimal sample of the problem, making sure the iframe has loaded a certain jQuery.js (then ajax should have the cached script) before some other stuff is added to the iframe.

Click load, and after while, console log will show "after awhile... dialog is undefined" - only when ajax was used.

**Update**: It looks like `$.get('jquery.js')` actually runs the script. `$.get('alert.js')` shows an alert, when alert.js has an alert function. (In the case of jQuery, re-defining the global jQuery reference.) Why does jQuery's ajax have this behavior? Does this happen with all ajax implementations?

Comment: Are you talking about having scripts apply to dynamic content...?  or something else?

Comment: It would be easier to test for the error if you can turn this into a reduced test case in jsfiddle or something

Comment: Also, why are you running an ajax call to `jquery.js?`

Comment: I tried jsfiddle but it seems to require same-domain. I was loading with ajax so I know inserting plugin scripts later will work since I have jQuery.

Comment: if you load jQuery again....will wipe out any existing plugins bound to initial jQuery object. Overwrites the inital jQuery object. Should start by explaining what the situation is.

Comment: @charlietfl Why would running one ajax request cause jQuery to be replaced by a new jQuery though?

Comment: have you checked the jquery you are loading is inside iframe and not on top of your current page ?

Comment: `$.get('jquery.js')` .... are you really doing this? Again...your code is very fuzzy...explain in detail what you are doing

Comment: what you are trying to do actually ?

Comment: That was to make sure jquery had actually reached the browser, before inserting more scripts, otherwise they fail (no jQuery reference). Maybe there's better way to do this, but there still seems to be a bug in jQuery ajax. Run that example with and without the jQuery ajax - ajax is breaking stuff, somehow.

Comment: if you have plugins that load before jQuery they will throw errors. These comments  aren't working. You need to fully detail your scenario fromm start to end. Have no idea what you are trying to do

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, that is why I'm waiting for it by requesting the script with ajax, then I insert others - and it does work. I'm wondering why calling ajax replaces the global "jQuery" reference. Adding jQuery = $ after ajax success fixes it, but I have no idea why this happens.

Comment: Let's say for the sake of argument that you've discovered a bug. It still doesn't make sense to be trying to retrieve jquery.js via an Ajax call. If you want to do something after a script has loaded, add a `'load'` event handler to the script element that you're creating. And given that your whole function depends on jQuery in the first place _none_ of your code will run until after the browser has a copy of jquery.js in its cache...

Comment: I'd suggest not using iframes at all, or use the parent window's jQuery instead. It'd save you some headaches.

Comment: Please reread the comments - This was making sure jQuery got loaded into dynamically generated iframe, before adding dependent scripts. I didn't know .load() would work for script tag.

Comment: BTW why did someone delete the answer that was just posted?

Comment: @NoBugs can you update your question, explaining what you are trying to achieve with the iframe? What are you going to use jQuery for after you have loaded it in the iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone answered earlier (whose answer got deleted?), jQuery ajax automatically chooses what to do depending on what type of content you requested. (An unfortunately under-documented feature). loading an external js will not just return when the browser has fetched the script, it will also **run** the script.

Whenever you re-include jQuery at a later point, it rewrites the window.jQuery object, therefore removing the jQuery.prototype.dialog, etc.

The Firefox .watch function can be helpful in cases like this, to see where something got redefined. This, for example, would give you a stack trace of anything that redefines jQuery:

```
window.watch('jQuery',function() { console.trace() } )
```