# JQuery auto executes javascript files right after fetched

Tags: jquery, ajax, file, execute

I would like first of all to shed some light on this matter, since I found **nothing** while searching online.

In jQuery 3.5.1 (at least, haven't seen others) when you execute a simple $.get(...) on a same-domain Javascript file, this file is instantly executed on load, from the jQuery code underline $.get function.
This happens with jQuery.globalEval, and because by default there is a converter installed by jQuery, for javascript files, that runs them.

But there comes a question. Who found auto-running javascript files a good idea and why?
When I say "fetch me a javascript" ( $.get("local-domai/file.js") ) I certainly do **NOT** expect
it to understand "oh, please run this javascript file"...
How come it was found as a good idea (in order to have been made it to distribution code)?

I mean, I understand to auto-convert json string to actual json when the filetype is appropriate (.json)
etc, but to run javascript files? Why?

Also, take note, this happends on local-domain js files only, "for security reasons", as stated in a comment of the code.

In case anyone else stumbles upon this problem, the solution I found was to take down this nasty converter of course (after one hour of searching the code ... ):

```js
jQuery.ajaxSettings.contents.script = false;
```

In more detail can be found in this issue report I just made:
https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/4822

Comment: Yeah, that's a very peculiar design decision.. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19872285/why-does-jquerys-ajax-automatically-run-scripts

Comment: I vote to close: The question is `How come it was found as a good idea` ?  - This really sounds like an SO out of scope question.

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance, I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Update: Looks like this might change is jQuery 4
https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/4822